# Using timers in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, timer, scripting

I'm trying to figure out how to use a timer in Windows PowerShell. I want my script to run a command/task for a certain amount of time, stop the task, and then output the results to a txt file. Here is what I have so far:

```
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

while ($timer.elapsed.totalseconds -lt 10){

netstat 169.254.219.44 

$timer.stop() | 
Out-File $PSScriptroot\connections.txt

break
}
```

All the script does is run the command in the terminal until I press ctrl+c. Once I press ctrl+c it stops and then outputs the .txt file. But the .txt file is blank. I've spent way more time than I should've trying to figure this out. I'm new to Windows PowerShell and was just messing around to see what I could do. There's no real purpose for this script. It's just driving me nuts that I can't figure this out...

Comment: you are STOPPING the timer _inside your `while` loop_. that means your test will never trigger. [*grin*]

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking to have the test repeat continuously until the allowed time elapses?  Whatever code is in your while {} block will repeat as long as the condition `($timer.elapsed.totalseconds -lt 10)` is true.  As [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) mentioned, don't stop the timer in your loop.

```
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($timer.elapsed.totalseconds -lt 10) {
    # Code in here will repeat until 10 seconds has elapsed
    # If the netstat command does not finish before 10 seconds then this code will 
    # only run once

    # Maybe separate each netstat output in the file with date/time
    "*** " + (Get-Date) + " ***" | Out-File $PSScriptroot\connections.txt -Append
    netstat 169.254.219.44 | Out-File $PSScriptroot\connections.txt -Append
}

$timer.stop()
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't notice that... Thank you for your answers. That helps a lot and it makes sense now. I just wanted it to run netstat for a set amount of time and show me the results in a .txt file. This should accomplish that now.